# Pinterest Rich Pins - Price

Tags: pinterest

we have this code for each product:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Lotuscrafts" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/yogadecke-savasana-100-baumwolle-kba" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Yogadecke &quot;Savasana&quot; 100% Baumwolle (kbA)" />
<meta property="og:description" content="  Vielseitig anwendbar in der Yogapraxis  Klassische, handgewebte Yogadecke, ideal als unterst&uuml;tzende Unterlage in der Asana Praxis, im Meditationssitz oder f&uuml;r die Endentspannung.   Aus 100% Baumwolle, &ouml;kologisch gefertigt  Gefertigt..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/media/image/d2/6b/12/YBL-BO55f6c92eb882a.jpg" />
<meta property="product:brand" content="Yogi" />
<meta property="product:price" content="29,95" />
<meta property="product:product_link" content="http://www.example.com/yogadecke-savasana-100-baumwolle-kba" />
```

In the Pinterest docs (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/products/) I can see that `product:price:amount` and `product:price:currency` are required. In the example code it's mentioned this code (og instead of product as written in the docs)

```
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="98.00" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
```

Which one is correct? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest no longer supports price variations or ranges unless you are using a feed partner like Shopify.